# How can I create a discount code which allows the customer to get a specific item free if they spend over £300?

Tags: discount, coupon-codes, code, free-gift

Either by having this item in their basket anyway and subtracting the value from the order or it would be great if the code added the item on to the order for free, without them having to search for it and place it in there themselves.

I've followed some advice I've found around the web for similar questions but nothing has worked. Thanks!

Comment: You can make cart price rule in magento admin .marketing ->cart price rule

Comment: I have been doing but it doesn't apply the code, saying it's not valid. Not sure where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to observe the magento event sales_quote_collect_totals_after and add the product here via code. The hard part is, making sure the product gets removed from the quote when the value of the cart is reduced.

I'm using the following extension on quite a high traffic project with no issues; https://cunningpro.com/add-free-promotional-product-to-cart.html

This extension doesn't use coupon codes, but you could easily edit the code in Promoproduct/Model/Observer.php to check for existence of your coupon code before adding the promoproduct.

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there no way to do it without an extension? I would be happy with the code just subtracting the value of the item with it in the cart.